# asp.net using CALENDAR

Tags: jquery, asp.net, calendar, datepicker

I am looking to display a calendar on screen, and I need to pass a list of dates to the calendar. Each date will be highlighted in bold on the calendar to show which dates have been stored.

I was considering using the JQuery datepicker, but I think the asp:calendar might be better. Does anyone have any suggestions or know where I should start?

---

EDIT: So for a test run I went with datepicker using:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

        <script>
            $(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
            });
        </script>

   <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
```

Now I have a list of dates stored in cs page as.

```
 DateTime start = new DateTime(2013, 02, 20);
        DateTime end = new DateTime(2013, 01, 11);

        var dates = new List<DateTime>();

        for (var dt = start; dt <= end; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
        {
            dates.Add(dt);
        }
```

does anyone have any idea how I can pass the list to the calendar so the calendar will highlight the dates which are in the list. thank you

Comment: ASP Calendar is junk.  Consider JQuery fullcalendar: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Comment: I have just done similar in asp, as above I suggest fullCalendar

Comment: If you are using WebForms I would also suggest the Telerik toolkit.

Comment: I think your edit makes it a completely different question and you should start a new thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see no reason not to use the regular ASP.NET calendar for this purpose. Take a look at the following tutorial:

[Highlighting Important Dates in Calendar](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7929/Highlighting-Important-Dates-in-Calendar)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use [JQuery calendar](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) as you have various options for theming as you don't have with asp.net ajax controls.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using JQuery plugins whenever possible over ASP or Ajax Toolkit controls.

Comment: Without much more details or an example, this is better as a comment then an answer.